# Excel (2013) I want to start it up on windows startup but don't show a window

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

is somehow possible to start Excel without opening a window?

I'm asking because I'm  tired from waiting for Excel to start (the green splashscreen) when opening a workbook. Now I starting excel on startup (with a new document), so every next document is opened immediately as long as there is running almost one excel process.

Comment: Can you add clarification to what you want that is functionally different from what montonero's answer describes (what you want that isn't accomplished by that solution)?  It seems like the only way to start an app and not show a window is to start it minimized.  If that isn't satisfactory, it isn't clear what you're after that's different.

Comment: @fixer1234 I believe OP wants to hide the window completely. A some kind of a "preload" to make a documents opening faster. I've made some tests and it will not quite work as OP expected. Hidden Excel will open documents faster (and its window become un-hidden) but when you close this document Excel will be closed completely. Therefore the whole point to run Excel as a hidden app is vanishing. Otherwise OP will need to hide the window every time instead of closing.

Answer (score 3):

You can set a window state in shortcut properties to a minimized.[image]

Comment: Thank you. But this is not what I meant. I want to run it in background - without any window visible.

Comment: @Lluser The problem is that you'll need to hide the window every time. If you open a document and then close it Excel will be closed completely.

Answer (score 1):

in a bat file you can put this line

```
start /min "" "E:\work\MyData\file1.xlsx"
start /min "" "C:\Downloads\file2.xls"
start /min "" "D:File3.xlsx"
```

or if all files are in a single folder on disk, you can use loop

```
for %%1 in (File1.xlsx File2.xls File3.xlsx) do (start "" "E:\MyData\%%1")
```

For this to work, you should already have attached xlsx and xls extenstions to MS Excel in defaults programs, which normally already happens at MS Office install.

then put a shortcut to this bat file on your desktop, once you reach desktop double click to run that, no UAC required, and all files will go on opening one by one minimized and you can do your other work in between.

or if you want that to be run automatically at each boot, put the bat file shortcut in shell:startup folder.